# Compare same values and keep biggest number's value in another column?

Tags: arcpy, geopandas, pandas

Here is an example to explain what I mean:

I want from this:

```
    index  area key
0      1    50  1f
1      2    60   2
2      3    70  3d
3      5    80   4
4      1    90   5
5      2   100   6
6      3    10   7
7      3    20   8
8      3    70   9
```

to go to this:

```
     index  area key key1
0      1    50  1f    5   <--new 'key1' column that keeps the value from 'key' where same 
1      2    60   2    6         numbers in 'index' have the largest area.
2      3    70  3d   3d
3      5    80   4    4    Example: Checks all 2 in index field which has the largest area 
4      1    90   5    5  since the largest area with index 2 has 100 in 'area' the'key1' 
5      2   100   6    6  field takes 5 in both positions. 
6      3    10   7   3d
7      3    20   8   3d
8      3    70   9   3d
```

I have managed to do this using pandas: This makes the first table:

```
import pandas as pd   # Think this as a shapefile's attribute table
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": [1,2,3,5,1,2,3,3,3], "area": 
[50,60,70,80,90,100,10,20,70], "key": ["1f",2,"3d",4,5,6,7,8,9]})
print (df)
```

And this makes the result:

```
df["rank_a"] = df.groupby("index")["area"].rank(ascending = False, method = "first")
df["key1_temp"] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row["key"]) if row["rank_a"] == 1.0 
else "", axis = 1)
df["key1"] = df.groupby("index")["key1_temp"].transform("sum")
print (df[["index", "area", "key", "key1"]])
```

## Purpose

**I want to make this in ArcPy.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read values using the da.SearchCursor into a list of lists, sort by area, create a dictionary of index:key. Key will be the one with the largest area since duplicates are replaced with the last duplicate in a dictionary. (Index 3 has two 70 areas, but different keys, you dont say how you want to handle this)

Example:

```
data = [[1,50,'1f'],
        [2,60,'2'],
        [3,70,'3d'],
        [5,80,'4'],
        [1,90,'5'],
        [2,100,'6'],
        [3,10,'7'],
        [3,20,'8'],
        [3,70,'9']]
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
d = {i[0]:i[2] for i in data}
>>d
{3: '9', 1: '5', 2: '6', 5: '4'}
```

Then write this to key1 field using da.UpdateCursor:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\feature'

data = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['index','area','key'])]
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
d = {i[0]:i[2] for i in data}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['index','key1']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = d[row[0]]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

(You can use pandas with arcpy. Since 10.4 (I think) pandas is installed with ArcGIS. You can create dataframes using da.SearchCursor and pd.DataFrame.from_records. Do the pandas processing and write results back using a dictionary)

Comment: Actually yes, I know about pandas' inclusion to Arc but I typically avoid using them in tricky situations that require swapping to feature classes from dataframe and the likes. About the index 3 having two 70 areas I have dealt by using `method = 'first'`. Thanks for the answer, I don't understand though the last part that you say 'Do the pandas processing and write results back using a dictionary)'. You suggest to do what I did and then turn it to dictionary? Is this a different approach from what you wrote in the code?

Comment: I mean that it is possible to create pandas df using da.SearchCursor and then write the data back to the features/shapefile using a [dictionary](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and the updatecursor. But in your case it is not necessary since your problem can be solved using only python.

Comment: You say only Python but the two ways we have here, mine and yours don't use only python.I am kind of confused sorry.

Comment: Also how am I supposed to make the initial dict, from a shapefile to begin with?

Comment: Im showing you in my answer. Or do you mean how to create a df from shapefile attribute table?

Comment: Since it has a lot of speculation, It would be better to think like a real situation of a shapefile. How do we start with process? Do we do this with the pandas or Arcpy way? Refer to the steps.

Comment: If its too much I am asking then  just add the 'from records' code to turn it to df and to dict using a shapefile and some comments for clarification and I think I will figure it out.

Comment: @user10680652 Im showing you exactly the way to do it in my answer. Just change `fc = r'C:\data.gdb\feature'` to `fc = r'C:\somefolder\someshapefile.shp'`. Your question was not how to do it using pandas. Post a new question if you want to ask Another question

Comment: The update cursor needs separate `'` in each field and also key1 hasn't be created yet so it gives column does not exist.

Comment: what about key1 that doesn't exist?

Comment: Just add the field